# How can I get all details objects with specified condition?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have

```
class A {
  String title
  static hasMany = [details: Detail]
}

class Detail {
  enum Type { ONE, TWO }

  String name
  Type type

  static belongsTo = [a: A]
}
```

How can I get list of all Details type ONE for specified object a?

I tried

```
def all_one = A.get(params.id).details.findByType(Detail.Type.ONE)
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to use the Groovy collections API to do:

```
A.get(params.id).details.findAll { it.type == Detail.Type.ONE }
```

Or, you might be able to go from the Detail back up with:

```
Detail.findByAAndType( A.get(params.id), Detail.Type.ONE )
```

Though I haven't tested that out...